# Compactly generated spaces as quotients of topological sums of compact Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have two questions about Proposition 7.9.2 and Corollary 7.9.3 in tom Dieck's "Algebraic Topology".

Here is the setting, taken from Tammo tom Dieck: *Algebraic Topology*, European Mathematical Society, 2008 (Section 7.9):

> A compact Hausdorff space will be called a ch-space. For the purpose of the
> following investigations we also call a ch-space a ***test space*** and a continuous map $f: C \to X$ of a test space $C$ a ***test map***. [...]

> A subset $A$ of a topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is said to be ***k-closed (k-open)***, if for each test map $f: K \to X$ the pre-image $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed (open) in $K$. The k-open sets in $(X, \mathcal{T})$ form a topology $k\mathcal{T}$ on $X$. A closed (open) subset is also k-closed (k-open). Therefore $k\mathcal{T}$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}$ and the identity $\iota=\iota_X: kX \to X$ is continuous. We set $kX = k(X) = (X, k\mathcal{T})$. [...]

> A topological space $X$ is called ***k-space***, if the k-closed sets are closed, i.e., if $X = kX$. [...]

> The next proposition explains the definition of a k-space. We call a topology $\mathcal{S}$ on $X$ ch-definable, if there exists a family $(f_j: K_j \to X \,|\, j \in J)$ of test maps such that: $A \subset X$ is $\mathcal{S}$-closed $\Leftrightarrow$ for each $j \in J$ the pre-image $f_j^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $K_j$. We can rephrase this condition: The canonical map $\langle f_j \rangle: \bigsqcup_j K_j \to (X,\mathcal{S})$ is a quotient map. A ch-definable topology is finer than $\mathcal{T}$. We define a partial ordering on the set of ch-definable topologies by $\mathcal{S}_1 \leq \mathcal{S}_2 \Leftrightarrow \mathcal{S}_1 \supset \mathcal{S}_2$.

> **(7.9.2) Proposition.** *The topology $k\mathcal{T}$ is the maximal ch-definable topology with respect to the partial ordering.*

> *Proof.* By Zorn’s Lemma there exists a maximal ch-definable topology $\mathcal{S}$. If this topology is different from $k\mathcal{T}$, then there exists an $\mathcal{S}$-open set $U$, which is not
> k-open. Hence there exists a test map $t: K \to X$ such that $t^{-1}(U)$ is not open. If we adjoin this test map to the defining family of $\mathcal{S}$, we see that S is not maximal.

> **(7.9.3) Corollary.** *The k-spaces are the spaces which are quotients of a topological sum of ch-spaces.*

My questions:

(1) Why do we need Zorn's Lemma? Isn't it true by definition of $k\mathcal{T}$ that this is the coarsest topology on $X$ which is ch-definable? Thus, in particular, it should be a maximal element with respect to the above partial ordering, or what am I missing?

(2) Why is every k-space (homeomorphic to) a quotient of a disjoint union of ch-spaces? Since $k\mathcal{T}$ is a ch-definable topology on $X$ (essentially by definition), there exists a quotient map of the form $\langle f_j \rangle: \bigsqcup_j K_j \to (X,k\mathcal{T})$, so if $X$ is a $k$-space, then $X=kX=(X,k\mathcal{T})$ is bijective to such a quotient. But why is there a homeomorphism? Sorry if this is obvious.

Any help is much appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: $1)$ As specified by tom Dieck, it's not obvious that $k\mathcal{T}$ is definable by means of a *set*. The lemma is the statement that it is. $2)$ $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a k-space iff $\mathcal{T}=k\mathcal{T}$. i.e. iff $X\cong kX$. But $kX$ is a quotient of a ch-space. Again the important point is that there is a *set* of compact Hausdorff spaces (and not just a proper class) which determines the topology on $kX$.

Comment: @Tyrone i read that definition as that is by definition defined by a set of maps indexed by $I$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma the definition of ch-definable or the definition of $kX$ as given in the book? In the book $kX$ is given the topology $k\mathcal{T}$ generated by the the family of k-open subsets of $X$. It's not clear at the outset that this topology should be the final topology specified by a *set* of test maps (ie. ch-definable).

Comment: @Tyrone ch-definable as given in the post. That definition is for a set of maps, right?  The OP didn’t define another notion of $k$-space.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes. As I understand it ch-definable is implies a set of maps (which should explain the wording of my previous comment if it was unclear). tom Dieck defines $kX$ in his book (p.187) in the standard way just before introducing the notion of ch-definable.

Comment: A ch-definable topology is finer than $\mathcal{T}$ it says, what is that $\mathcal{T}$ in that context?

Comment: Thank you for your comments! $\mathcal{T}$ is the given topology on $X$. Sorry, I have left out some important passages from the book when posting my question. I will add the relevant ones.

Comment: I think Tyrone is right. I did not realize that the class of all test maps to $X$ is not a set. Now, tom Dieck's proof makes sense, thanks! However, I still do not understand (2). @Tyrone: You said that $kX$ is a quotient of a ch-space, but how do you see this? Or did you mean a quotient of a topologcial sum of ch-spaces?

Comment: You've found my typo! I should have said that $kX$ is ch-definable, and is a quotient of a *locally* compact Hausdorff space (i.e. a disjoint sum $\bigsqcup K_i$ of compact Hausdorff spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the comments, I would like to answer my first question:

The class of all test maps to $X$ is not in general a set, so it is not clear from the definition of $k\mathcal{T}$ that this topology is ch-definable. Tom Dieck uses Zorn's Lemma in order to obtain a maximal ch-definable topology on $X$ with respect to the partial ordering he has defined, and then he shows that this topology is $k\mathcal{T}$. In particular, this implies that $k\mathcal{T}$ *is* in fact ch-definable.

And I think I have found an answer to my second question:

If $X=(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a k-space, that is, $\mathcal{T}=k\mathcal{T}$, then by the proposition, its topology is ch-definable, so there exists a quotient map $q: Z\to X$ for some topological sum $Z$ of ch-spaces. We define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $Z$ by $z_1\sim z_2 \Leftrightarrow q(z_1)=q(z_2)$. Then $q$ induces a well-defined bijective continuous map $f:Z/\!\sim\, \to X$ satisfying $f\circ p = q$ where $p:Z\to Z/\!\sim$ is the canonical projection.
This map $f$ is a homeomorphism: Given an open subspace $U\subset Z/\!\sim$, we need to show that the image $f(U)$ is open in $X$, or equivalently, that $q^{-1}(f(U))$ is open in $Z$ (since $q:Z\to X$ is a quotient map). This is true because $q^{-1}(f(U)) = (f\circ p)^{-1}(f(U)) = p^{-1}(f^{-1}(f(U))) = p^{-1}(U)$ (by injectivity of $f$), which is open in $Z$ (by definition of the quotient topology on $Z/\!\sim$).
Hence, $X$ is homeomorphic to the quotient $Z/\!\sim$.

Comment: Looks good to me :)

Comment: Sorry, but I still have a question concerning this matter. Why couldn't we just take the intersection of all ch-definable topologies on $X$? This is again ch-definable (consider the union of all families coming along with the ch-definable topologies), and it is maximal with respect to the partial order. So why do we need Zorn's Lemma?

Comment: For that we need first to show that $X$ admits any ch-definable topology at all, and the easiest way to show this is probably use Zorn's Lemma anyway.

Comment: Doesn't Zorn's Lemma require the existence of a ch-definable topology? I think we could take the discrete topology: It is the final topology induced by the empty family (or by the family of all inclusions $\{x\}\hookrightarrow X$ with $x\in X$ to avoid the empty family), so in particular, it is ch-definable, isn't it?

Comment: (Yes the discrete topology is ch-definable.) The problem is that at some point you are going to have to invoke the axiom of choice. It's not immediate that an arbitrary join of ch-definable topologies will be ch-definable. You've indicated an idea above to take the union of all families coming from ch-definable topologies. Thus requires a fixed choice of presentation for every ch-definable topology. For example take the set of all singletons. This realises the discrete topology. But so does any other discrete set of the same cardinality, and there are already a proper class of these.

Comment: If you make a choice of presentation for each ch-definable topology, then, as you suggest, you can just take the union of the presentations and you end up with something defining kX. tom Dieck uses Zorn's Lemma to arrange these details. If you look in R. Brown's book Topology and Groupoids, you'll see a similar statement on p.182. Brown doesn't make any mention of Zorn's Lemma, but you can see immediately where he invokes AOC.

Comment: @ Tyrone: Thanks a lot!